# Return 1 or 0 if mysql column has data

Tags: mysql, pdo

I would like to return 1 or 0 (or true or false, or true or null, or whatever is easiest) if a given column has any data.  Regardless of whether this field has data, the other columns would still be returned. Is below the correct way?  Thanks

```
SELECT varchar_field IS NOT NULL, some_other_fields
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT ISNULL(varchar_field), some_other_fields
```

if you want 0 when `varchar_field` isnt `null`

```
SELECT NOT ISNULL(varchar_field), some_other_fields
```

if you want 1 when `varchar_field` isnt `null`

Comment: Is this any faster than my original suggestion or Neo's?

Comment: i dont know if it is faster, but it´s more readable in my opinion and as result you get 1 or 0 as you wanted

Comment: Actually, this returns 0 if the column has data.

Comment: SELECT NOT ISNULL(varchar_field), some_other_fields will work

Comment: sorry, but then your question really isnt clear: 'I would like to return 1 or 0 (...) if a given column has any data'. Of course you get the values inverted if you write a NOT in front of it...

Comment: Thanks, I will go with your solution.  It appears that my original "varchar_field IS NOT NULL" will not eve work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `case` statement

```
CASE WHEN varchar_field is null 
THEN 1
ELSE 0
END
```

Comment: IFNULL() appears to only accept two arguments.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull

Comment: Yes, my mistake. You can use case statement to achieve what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Agree that the case will work, but Obl's seems a little ore readable.